# Faster alternative to STL std::map

Tags: c++, boost, stl

I do have a data structure:

```
typedef std::pair<boost::shared_ptr<X>, boost::shared_ptr<X> > pair_ptr;
std::map< pair_ptr, int >
```

that I use in a iterative process. In each iteration I *need* to copy the the std::map and possibly destroy one copy. However, the std::map can become large, over 100k elements. This significantly slows down the program. I've defined the operator< as:

```
   inline bool operator<(const pair_ptr& a, const pair_ptr& b) 
   { 
   return (a.first < b.first) or 
        (a.first == b.first and a.second < b.second);
   }
```

I use the std::map copy constructor and destructor. Is there a faster alternative?

Comment: How did you compile? With what compiler (& version)? Did you enable optimizations? On which computer & operating system?

Comment: gnu c++, gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3), build type flags:  -O2 -g

Comment: Redesign your program so you don't _need_ to copy huge maps around each iteraton.

Comment: have you considered `unordered_map`?

Comment: Have you looked into `std::unordered_map` or `boost::flat_map`?

Comment: @JesperJuhl, no, this might be an option.

Comment: If the problem really is due to making the copies, I doubt copying a huge `unordered_map` will be much faster than copying a huge `map`. It might be faster to access elements in it, but not to copy it. Copying it will still need to allocate 100k nodes and link them all together.

Comment: I'm with Ocelot on this. Even `flat_map` won't help much, because while you will have far fewer allocations to copy around, you're still doing hundreds of thousands of atomic increments/decrements. This is an algorithmic problem, and an algorithmic solution would be best.

Comment: Agreed, no Boost nor STL container alone is going to solve this. I would look into implementing a "delta overlaid" map which overlays change deltas onto an existing STL associative, the same way the LLVM string implementation can be chains of views of other strings. That lets you eliminate unnecessary copying. Also look into Howard Hinnant's node_ptr container extensions, lets you rebuild a new map from an old map without malloc getting involved (i.e. much quicker)

Comment: @NiallDouglas do you have any links for that?

Comment: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3645.pdf. Apologies for saying it was only Howard's idea, quite a few others are involved including @JonathanWakely

Comment: It's Alan Talbot's proposal. http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0083r2.pdf is the latest public version, p0083r3 was voted into C++17 and will be available next week.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a lot of choices - and we can suggest design alternatives but don't have enough information to make them for you.

Here are three things you could do:

1. Can you make the key a pointer to the pairs (and adjust the
   comparison appropriately) so that the pairs themselves (containing
   two refcnt'd ptrs) don't have to be copied?
2. In each iteration - do you need the expected `O(log n)`
   insertion/deletion time? If you can live with `O(n)`
   insertion/deletion then can you use a sorted vector as the container
   instead of a map? (So that you allocate/free the container in one
   shot instead of allocate/free lots of little tree nodes.) (Remember: a `std::map`
   isn't the only data structure you can search in, not even the only `std::`
   data structure.  All searchable data structures will work, just choose
   the one that has the appropriate complexity guarantees, modulo your 
   knowledge of the "constants" (e.g., heap allocation is expensive), for your 
   use case.)
3. Can you (do you) manage the lifetimes of the two things the key is
   pointing at independent of the map, and this iterative process? If
   so you can have a key of a pair of naked pointers, which will be faster than
   ref cnt'd pointers on creation of the new map at each iterator. You
   can have a separate set of ref cnt'd pointers to all your things,
   and manage the lifetime of these objects there.

These can be combined, too.  Just some ideas to get you started.

Comment: These are some good suggestions. 1) is definitely possible; 2) is closest to what I wanted to know; 3) I'm not too keen on using naked pointers, but it would be an option as well. <br/> From the discussion above it seems that it is the best way to avoid the copying altogether, even if this requires some substantial refactoring. That is what I'm going to do.